# PHP Functions and MySQL Connectivity

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a database.php file which stores the database connection info like this:

```
<?php

// Database connectivity stuff

$host     = "localhost"; // Hostname for the database. Usually localhost
$username = "root"; // Username used to connect to the database
$password = "root"; // Password for the username used to connect to the database
$database = "blog"; // The database used

// Connect to the database using mysqli_connect
$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);

// Check the connection for errors
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($connection)) {
    // Stop the whole page from loading if errors occur
    die("<br />Could not connect to the database. Please check the settings and try again.") . mysqli_connect_error() . mysqli_connect_errno();
}


?>
```

And also a functions.php file that has the following:

```
<?php

// Functions file for the system
function show_posts($user_id) {
    $posts = array();
    $sql = "SELECT body, stamp from posts where user_id = '$user_id' order by stamp desc";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
}

function show_users() {
    $users = array();
    $sql = "SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE status = 'active' ORDER BY username";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $users[$data->id] = $data->username;
    }
    return $users;
}

function following($user_id) {
    $users = array();
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM following WHERE follower_id = $user_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        array_push($users, $data->user_id);
    }
    return $users;
}

?>
```

Both files are inside an /includes folder. I now have a users.php files in which I want to display a list of users. Here's my code that *tries* to do that:

```
<?php

        $users = show_users();
        foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
          echo $key . " " . $value;
        }

?>
```

The problem I have is this:

> Notice: Undefined variable: connection in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blog/includes/functions.php on line 13
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
>   in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blog/includes/functions.php on line 13
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blog/includes/functions.php on
>   line 15

The users.php file has require('includes/functions.php') and require('includes/database.php'). But somehow the values are not *passed?*. What am I doing wrong? Please help me out. I hope this makes sense. The problem with the undefined variable occurs for each function of the 3.

Comment: Its a variable scope issue you're defining your $connection etc outside of the functions so the functions have no access to the connection you need to pass your connection variable into your functions so you can use it

Comment: So I should just move the contents of database.php in functions.php?

Comment: Like function show_users($connection) {

Comment: no just pass $connection in as a parameter like this `function show_posts($connection,$user_id) {`

Answer (score 0):

Either pass the `$connection` variable to your functions or make it global.

E.g:

```
function show_posts($connection, $user_id) {
    $posts = array();
    $sql = "SELECT body, stamp from posts where user_id = '$user_id' order by stamp desc";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
}
```

OR

```
function show_posts($user_id) {
    global $connection;

    $posts = array();
    $sql = "SELECT body, stamp from posts where user_id = '$user_id' order by stamp desc";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
}
```

Comment: Do NOT make them global that is a dumb thing to do.

Comment: I've tried putting the $connection in my show_posts and following fuctions, and I still get the same error. What am I doing wrong? Here's my current functions.php http://pastebin.ca/2495407 -- And here's my users.php that tries to display the users http://pastebin.ca/2495408

Comment: if passing `$conection` doesn't work, you might have a problem with scoping: `$conection` is created in a scope and you are trying to use it in another. Analyze your traceback to see if you're running some script inside a function. Also, is this **Wordpress**??

Answer (score 0):

Try $GLOBALS['connection'] instead of $connection in your function. See more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Then you should try using object oriented approach.There are many tutorials available.